# Spring Boot/Hibernate: Not Found error when I text my code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to create a project in spring boot and when I go to test my app via Postman I get the following error:
{
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "",
"path": "/ api / customers-list"
}

I explain in detail what the problems were.

I initially encountered the following error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

which I solved by simply inserting the following line in application.properties (I don't know if that's a good way, but it seems to have solved anyway):

```js
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Subsequently I found the error above (ie that of not found). I checked carefully if there was any typo in entering the URL, I checked if I ran the right application and it seems that everything is correct but I am unable to interact with Postman due to Not Found.

How can I solve this problem? I hope someone will help me.

Code:

pom.xml

```js
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Config.java

```js
package pack_cap_Config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("boot.entry"),
          @ComponentScan("Model"),
          @ComponentScan("Controller"),
          @ComponentScan("DAO"),
          @ComponentScan("Miscallaneous"),
          @ComponentScan("Service")})
public class Config {

     @Value("${db.driver}")
        private String DB_DRIVER;

        @Value("${db.password}")
        private String DB_PASSWORD;

        @Value("${db.url}")
        private String DB_URL;

        @Value("${db.username}")
        private String DB_USERNAME;

        @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
        private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

        @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
        private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

        @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
        private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

        @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
        private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
            Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
            dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
            dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
            dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
            return txManager;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver= new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        } 
       
       
       
    }
```

```js
package pack_cap_Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import pack_cap_Model.Customer;
import pack_cap_Service.CaP_Service;



@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private CaP_Service capservice;
    
    @GetMapping("customers-list")
    public List<Customer> allcustomers() {
         return capservice.getCustomers();
    }
```

application.properties

```js
# Database
db.driver= com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acq
db.username=root
db.password=123456

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
entitymanager.packagesToScan=pack_cap_Model

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Try putting a slash before the customer-list url.   @GetMapping("/customers-list")

Comment: i tried but it still doesn't work

Comment: Why there are spaces between / api / customers-list in your error log

Comment: it is a copy/paste error but there are no spaces in the url

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was in the Spring Boot directory structure; I had wrong the structure of the different folders of the project.